# How to prove that $A^m$ is PSD

Tags: linear-algebra

If we know that matrix $A$ is positive semidefinite, how we can prove that $A^m$ is positive semidefinite for all $m \in \mathbb{Z}^+$.

Thanks

Comment: You could diagonalize $A$ via a unitary matrix, for instance.

Answer (score 4):

$A^m$ is symmetric and its eigenvalues are those of $A$ raised to the $m^{th}$ power. Since $A$ is positive-semidefinite, its eigenvalues are non-negative and so the same is true for the eigenvalues of $A^m$.